# Centering 3 divs in each row

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to center three divs in a row, but for some reason, I'm getting only 4 divs in one row, and the other two divs in a separate row, what am I doing wrong?

```
.container{
display: flex;                
justify-content: center; 
padding-top: 20px;
color:black;
padding-bottom: 30px;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: center;

.box{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #ccc;
    width:240px;
    margin: 16px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    
}


const Offer = (props) => {
  return (
    <div id="ser-id">

    <div className="box">
    <img className="icon" src={props.img} alt="" />
    <h2>{props.title}</h2>
    <p>{props.content}</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You miss a `}` after the `.container`. And where is the HTML is that `.container`?

Comment: If you mean to have 4 `.box` divs in a `.container` div, there is nothing wrong. You use flex and the number of boxes per line depends on the browser width. It varies from 4 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

With `flex-wrap: wrap` there will be as many child elements (= flex items) in a row as fit in due to their settings and the width of the container. So if you get four instead three in a row, either reduce the flex container's `width` or add some side padding (if `box-sizing` is *not*  `border-box`)

And you should erase that `float: left;`. In a flexbox context that makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Either you split using percentages and use the following for .box class:

```
.box{
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 33.33333333%;
}
```

or you give the .container a fixed width that is the sum of only 3 boxes so that only 3 fit and pushes the other 3 on the next row. Currently one box is set to 240px so if the container can fit 4 it will.

Comment: A second option would be to add a counter inside your reactjs code. You check the value of that counter and after every 3rd element you close the container and then open it again. Basically instead of having one row with 6 elements you have 2 rows with 3 elements each.